# Sequencial log file timestamp check

Tags: bash

I've got a large log file and I need to confirm the chronological timestamped entries sequence. I know how to read line 1 and extract the timestamp. I then need to compare it to lines 2 > line last. If there's any that are earlier than line 1 then print the whole line and continue until line last. Then read line 2 and repeat above for lines 3 >  line last. Then read line 3 and repeat above for lines 4 >  line last.   The outside loop reading from the log file is no problem but how do I read the same file again starting at the line n+1 compared to the line number the outside loop is reading please?    I.e. If the outside loop has read line 10, how do I get the inside loop to read the file starting at line 11? The log file has 10,000's line and I have several dozen log files to process, so speed is important.

Log file line format is:

Sep 17 16:09:51 2014  blah blah blah…
Sep 17 16:09:52 2014  blah blah blah…
Sep 17 16:09:52 2014  blah blah blah…
Sep 17 15:11:10 2014  blah blah blah…
Sep 17 16:11:10 2014  blah blah blah…

I'm trying to detect entries like line 4.
I can switch to Perl if it's faster.
Should I read the log file into an array to make the internal loop relative read position easy to do, or will the file size make the array size prohibitive?

Comment: Show us the format of the log entries. The solution may be as simple as testing whether the file is sorted by a certain field.

Comment: "so speed is important" then don't even think of using bash for an O(n^2) problem. Perl or Python would be considerably faster for the task. (yes I know it is still O(n^2) but the coefficient k where k << 1 is still faster)

Comment: What is your expected outcome here? If line 5 of a 5 line file is the earliest timestamp in the file the description above is going to print it out four time. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Ahhh, VERY good point Etan, I hadn't considered that. As these files are very long (to me) then I'll need to decide how to make it print out only once. Thank you.

Comment: If you just want to start reading a file at line X in `bash`, use `tail -n +X filename`, so if you wanted to start reading at line 11, use `tail -n +11 filename`.

Comment: Thanks zerodiff will do that.

Comment: I agree with Andy. Also, you can read 2 lines at the same time.. then you might not need 2 loops.

Comment: I've written the initial code in bash just to give me some idea of the speed and complexity of the code. The complexity is ok but the speed is, as expected, isn't up to it. Given that I reckon the task wil take 57 years to run in bash, how much of a speed increase/time decrease can I expect from perl please?